# How to fix the error, "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.surface.Surface, not tuple"

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

I am new to pygame and am trying to make a game with a bit of text, however when I run, I get the error, `TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.surface.Surface, not tuple`.
Here is my code:

```
import sys
import pygame
pygame.init()
# Make The Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
screen.fill((135, 206, 235))
# Font
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
while True:
    # make it work
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        screen.fill((250, 250, 0))
    # Try to make text happen
    ammo_text = font.render(f'Hello World', (0, 0, 100))
    screen.blit(ammo_text, (40, 250))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The error occurs in line 18 where I try to blit the text.

I tried a few different methods and the same error occured. I am open to ideas.
P.S. I don't need to know how to make text.

Comment: I don't see it.  What do you get if you `print(ammo_text)`?

Comment: @TimRoberts it puts this in the console: (<Surface(120x20x32 SW)>, <rect(1, 20, 120, 20)>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is due to differences between [pygame.Font.render()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) and [pygame.freetype.Font.render()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render).

The freetype font method returns a tuple, a `Surface` and `rect`. So you can change your code to ignore the returned `rect` :

```
ammo_text, _ = font.render(f'Hello World', (0, 0, 100))
```